# Installing YII and getting error due to environmental variable

Tags: php, frameworks, yii

I am new to this YII Framework. I am trying to install it using this [tutorial](http://tegarrputra.wordpress.com/2012/11/15/installing-yii-framework-on-windows-7/).

I am getting this error at last step:

> <<‘php.exe’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file>>

I am using Xamp on Windows 7.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program (...) Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C\xampp\php\
```

This is my environment variable path.

I searched a lot about that and found many solutions, but none of them are working me.

Comment: @Mike C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD (...) Server\90\Tools\binn\;C\xampp\php\php.exe
this thing also not working.

Comment: Edit your question instead, please. I don't know the answer, I just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted your computer yet? Windows doesn't reload the system environment variables once they're changed. The easiest way to force them to be applied is to restart the computer.

Comment: Have you tried `C:\xampp\php\php.exe path\to\framework\yiic webapp path\to\webapp\folder`